# Animation doesn't work properly with hardware acceleration

Tags: android, animation, webview

I am creating animation of three webviews at the same time. When I am turning off hardware acceleration there are moving correctly, but it's going wrong with it (it seems that only one is moving correctly, and other ones are waiting for animation end and  then moving to new positions immediately). What I am doing wrong? Have you seen such problems? 
I am using Android SDK 4.0 
Here's code:

```
ObjectAnimator[] anims = new ObjectAnimator[4];
float px = 10;
for( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    anims[i] = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(webViews[i], "translationX", px);


AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();

animSet.playTogether(anims);
animSet.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
animSet.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, but not with 3 webviews - it's probably more fluency-killing.  Anyway, try to set SDK target higher, it makes animation faster.

Comment: Might be right direction but it doesn't solve problem... It seems that it's not slowness problem but there's only one view animating at once. Thanks anyway.